# Can Shopware 6 App Override Twig Template Blocks In Administration?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I want to build a Shopware App instead of a Plugin and I would like to find out if I will be able to perform the following activities using an App extension.

1. Override twig template blocks with the Shopware 6 administration
2. Write custom JavaScript codes to manipulate the DOM of the Shopware 6 administration

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Override twig template blocks with the Shopware 6 administration
> 2. Write custom JavaScript codes to manipulate the DOM of the Shopware 6 administration

No, you won't be able to do neither. You gotta use and work within the constraints of the [Admin Extension SDK](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/) instead, if you want to influence the administration.